# Set corner radius to particular side of UIView/UIButton only

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, swift3, cornerradius

I want to set corner radius to my UI element as shown in attached snap:

[image]

I tried setting corner radius using `UIBezierPath` but it doesn't give expected result. I also added those three `UIButton`s in `UIView` and set corner radius to Container view but no use.

With reference to https://stackoverflow.com/a/31233171/4886069 , Following is the code what I've tried on top and bottom buttons:

```
let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
rectShape.bounds = self.scanButton.frame
rectShape.position = self.scanButton.center
rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.scanButton.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).cgPath
self.scanButton.layer.mask = rectShape

let rectShape1 = CAShapeLayer()
rectShape1.bounds = self.manualButton.frame
rectShape1.position = self.manualButton.center
rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.manualButton.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).cgPath
self.manualButton.layer.mask = rectShape1
```

Following is the code what I've tried on container view:

```
containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
```

following is the output what I got:

[image]

Any help appreciated. Thank you

Comment: is there 2 uiview you use for one is cancel and one is for  3 option ?

Comment: no. Cancel button is out of container view. Cancel button corner radius is working fine as cancelButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15

Comment: The scan button looks exactly like I'd expect it to given that mask. Any reason you're not just using UIAlertController with the action sheet style?

Comment: UIAlertController will pop from bottom and will stick to bottom of UIView. I want it to be at the centre of screen

Answer (score 0):

Use topRight, bottomLeft, and bottomRight in **byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft]** option for other corner for your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for giving Corner radius

```
let Path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: button.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.TopLeft , UIRectCorner.BottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0)).CGPath
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is for swift 2.0 just convert this code into swift 3.0

```
cancelbnutton.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
 cancelbnutton.clipsToBounds = true
 let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
 rectShape.bounds = scanbutton.frame
 rectShape.position = scanbutton.center

 rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: scanbutton.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.TopLeft , UIRectCorner.TopRight], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(10, 10)).CGPath
 scanbutton.layer.mask = rectShape

 let rectShape1 = CAShapeLayer()
 rectShape1.bounds = manualbutton.frame
 rectShape1.position = manualbutton.center

 rectShape1.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: manualbutton.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.BottomLeft , UIRectCorner.BottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(10, 10)).CGPath
 manualbutton.layer.mask = rectShape1
```

[image: output]

Comment: i just give above code to UIButton and its display same like you want