# UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer not creating corner line

Tags: ios, swift, cornerradius

This is my code

```
public func setMaskTo(setMask:UIView, corner:UIRectCorner) -> Void {
        let round = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: setMask.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corner, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10))
        let shape = CAShapeLayer()
        shape.frame = round.bounds
        shape.path = round.cgPath
        setMask.layer.mask = shape
    }

setMaskTo(setMask: self, corner: [.topLeft, .topRight])
```

Here my output

> 

[image]

Can anybody explain where I'm wrong with ? It's on Swift 3.

Thanks,

Comment: you want to create top left and right corners round of a specific view ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40169745/set-corner-radius-to-particular-side-of-uiview-uibutton-only/40170598#40170598 refer this question and answer

Comment: @vaibhav Yes, I want to round the corner of a UITextField. Top left and right.

Comment: I think there is a same background issue, its working fine in swift 2.2.

Comment: @vaibhav Its working when there is backgroundColor and no borderWidth. if setMask.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    setMask.layer.borderWidth = 0.6                          setMask.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear   then it's corner is not showing.

Comment: @DeepakKumarSahu okay then its great.

Comment: What if we want to apply different corner radius for all corners? Every answer is about same corner radius value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I got the answer!!!

Try with [UIBezierPath and CAShapeLayer not creating corner line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40303353/6280713)

```
var borderShape = CAShapeLayer() 
borderShape.path = round.cgPath
borderShape.lineWidth = 1.0
borderShape.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
borderShape.fillColor = nil
borderShape.frame = setMask.bounds
setMask.layer.addSublayer(borderShape)
```

Answer (score -1):

Better To Use a generic Extension:

```
extension UIView {

func roundedCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, conrnerRadius: CGFloat) {

    let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
    rectShape.bounds = self.frame

    rectShape.position = self.center
    rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [UIRectCorner.TopLeft , UIRectCorner.TopRight], cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(conrnerRadius, conrnerRadius)).CGPath

    self.layer.mask = rectShape

}
}
```

Call to the Function:

```
 oneextraview.roundedCorners(corners: [UIRectCorner.topRight, UIRectCorner.bottomRight], conrnerRadius: 10.0)
 oneextraview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
 oneextraview.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
 oneextraview.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

> **Note:** Either declare the extention in the **ViewController** file outside the class or in a sperate swift file

[image: output]

Comment: Can u add a borderWidth and color. backgroundColor to clear color.

Comment: in view i give background color clear color and border color ?

Comment: any color to border and any width to border width. Do not add clear or black. Check working or not.

Comment: @DeepakKumarSahu The code is tested and working. Can you post on what is the output that you are getting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40303353/6280713  end there is screenshot need to check.

Comment: @DeepakKumarSahu check my answer

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Just try with  oneextraview.layer.borderWidth = 1.0 instade of 5.0

Comment: @DeepakKumarSahu i also have face same issue when i change border width to 0.5f

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/40541254/6280713 it's adding a new layer which makes corner radial.