# How to set radius for bottom corners only

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

[image]

How would I set a radius for only the bottom two corners, like in the image above?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question!

Comment: @bub  I need to round only the tow bottom corners like the image.

Comment: Use `UIBezierPath`

Comment: Simply you can use an image.

Comment: this may be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/31233171/6619234

Comment: Don't hold me for a word, but I had problem with drawing CALayerShape using layout.

Answer (score 2):

I have just done that (For Swift 3, but it might help you as well), You should have an outlet to your image, for example called yourImage and then do this  On viewDidLoad:

```
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
   shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: yourImage.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)).cgPath
yourImage.layer.mask = shapeLayer
```

Comment: The OP is asking for Objective-C. You should provide both though as this will still work.

Comment: You are right, didn't saw that, unfortunately I don't know Objective C, Will edit my answer to let him now that.

Comment: Will see if it helps him, otherwise I could search.

Comment: Would you mind @MagoNicolasPalacios if I posted an Objective-c answer converted from your Swift 3.0 answer? :) I felt compelled to challenge myself to convert your answer. Geez, Objective-c is weird ever.

Comment: Awesome, because I don't know objective C :D

Comment: Remember to mark one of both answer as answered! since my Swift or prettigirls code should had help you.

Answer (score 2):

It's been literally MONTHS since the last time I've wrote an Objective-c code, since I want to tray it again, here's the Objective-c version of Mago Nicolas Palacios' answer written in Swift 3.0.

```
UIImageView *sampleImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sample"]];
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(30, 30);
UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:sampleImage.bounds
                                                 byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomRight | UIRectCornerTopLeft)
                                                       cornerRadii:size];
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[shapeLayer setPath:[bezierPath CGPath]];
sampleImage.layer.mask = shapeLayer;
```

Comment: Nice! You did it.