# How to add rounded corner at sides of UIView swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibezierpath, rounded-corners

I need add rounded corner bottom left and right am using UIView above the UIImageView. I have used CAShapeLayer but not cropped as per my requirement. Any solution to achieve this.[image: [1]]

Answer (score 7):

Here is how you add rounded corners to your views bottom corners:

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:customView.bounds, byRoundingCorners:[.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 50, height:  50))
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = path.cgPath 
customView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

Final result:
[image]

You will of course have to adjust it to your size and colouring.

Comment: I need this kind of UI. But by using your code i am unable to create it..What are the all possible measurement i need to add for uiview... Can you please explain?

Comment: does it need to have equal width and height?

Comment: @IdreesAshraf, no but the result will still be the same though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an extension of you UIView

It's nicely done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41217791/6423864)

You just have to change it to to :

`yourView.roundCorners([.bottomRight, .bottomLeft], radius: YOUR_RADIUS)`