# Create topLeft and topRight corners with border?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

This code creating only topLeft border, but i want topRight also. How?

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.colorSliderBackgroundView.bounds
                             byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                   cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0,10.0)];

CAShapeLayer *borderLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
borderLayer.frame = self.colorSliderBackgroundView.bounds;
borderLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;

borderLayer.lineWidth   = 1.5f;
borderLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243.0/255.0 green:243.0/255.0 blue:243.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
borderLayer.fillColor   = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

[self.colorSliderBackgroundView.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];
```

Comment: You should update shapelayer's path with colorSliderBackgroundView's bounds changes.

Comment: @ Cy-4AH, can you write code

Comment: @iOS - do you want `colorSliderBackgroundView` to be outlined, with rounded top corners? Or do you want `colorSliderBackgroundView` to have a ***sublayer*** that is an outlined rectangle with rounded top corners?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, it looks like you want an outlined rectangle with the top-left and top-right corners rounded, as a sublayer of another view...

Create a new view class, and set it as the custom class of your `colorSliderBackgroundView`.

---

**TopCornersRoundedView.h**

```
//
//  TopCornersRoundedView.h
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 10/30/19.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

IB_DESIGNABLE

@interface TopCornersRoundedView : UIView

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

---

**TopCornersRoundedView.m**

```
//
//  TopCornersRoundedView.m
//  ObjCXIBTest
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 10/30/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Don Mag. All rights reserved.
//

#import "TopCornersRoundedView.h"

@interface TopCornersRoundedView ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) CAShapeLayer *borderLayer;

@end

@implementation TopCornersRoundedView

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder {
    [super prepareForInterfaceBuilder];
    [self commonInit];
}

- (void) commonInit {

    // instantiate the shape layer
    _borderLayer = [CAShapeLayer new];

    // set line width, stroke and fill colors
    _borderLayer.lineWidth   = 1.5f;
    _borderLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243.0/255.0 green:243.0/255.0 blue:243.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    _borderLayer.fillColor   = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

    // add the shape layer as a sublayer of self
    [self.layer addSublayer:_borderLayer];

}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // create a bezier path with top left and right corners rounded
    // doing this in layoutSubviews will keep the frame size correct when
    // the view changes size
    UIBezierPath *maskPath;
    maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds
                                     byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                           cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0,10.0)];

    _borderLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    _borderLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;

}

@end
```

By designating this class as `IB_DESIGNABLE` you will even see the result at design-time:

[image]

Comment: ? Why not just use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/2877488-maskedcorners?language=objc

Comment: Hmm... I should have asked in comments for clarification on the OP's goal.

Comment: @matt - as a side note, the apps I work on still support back to iOS 9... since `.maskedCorners` arrived in iOS 11, it's not the first approach that comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

All you need todo is this:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer]; 
UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:frame byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight) 
 cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(3.0, 3.0)]; 
layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath; 
view.layer.mask = layer;
```

Or you can check this link for further detail

[how to set cornerRadius for only bottom-left,bottom-right and top-left corner textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232689/how-to-set-cornerradius-for-only-bottom-left-bottom-right-and-top-left-corner-te/46408735)