# Round top corners

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, rounded-corners

I have a question regarding rounding corners of a UIview. I drew up a design for an ios app with the top two edges (left and right) being slightly rounded. I was told that it is impossible to build but wanted to check here if it is, in fact, not possible to construct.

Thank you!

[image: screenshot of design]

Comment: There is almost nothing impossible sir ... yes it can be developed ....

Comment: check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/31233171/3719248

Comment: Take a look to my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46408735/5575955