# Animate height constraint doesn't work as expected

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, uiviewanimation

I am trying to animate a view in a ViewController using Layout Constraints. My goal is to transform the view's height from 0 to `finalHeight` in order to make the view "appears" from the bottom.

Right now I am testing making the view *grow* from 90 points to 150 points and even though the animation is working as expected the view's background is not behaving as expected.

When growing the view, the bottom of the view is stick at the bottom of the screen, the problem is that the view's original height is preventing (I guess) the background color to fill the new height and then the animation is not what it should be.

Here is an example of the current animation:

[image: view]

As you see the image appears to be translating the y-axis, but in reality, it's animating the view height constraint.

This is the code:

```
    func didRequestMatch(friend: Friend) {
        self.friendChallengeLabel.text = friend.name.isEmpty ? friend.email : friend.name
        self.challengeViewHeight.constant = 140
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

To show that the animation is actually changing the view's height and not the y-axis here is a screenshot of the Debug View Hierarchy

[image: view_h]

Here you can actually see that the new view's height is 140

```
Printing description of $16:
<UIView: 0x7fc119419eb0; frame = (87.5 527; 200 140); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; autoresizesSubviews = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002b66ec0>>
```

The way the view is created is from the Storyboard as follows:

[image: constraints]

Do you know what could be wrong?

Thank you so much

Comment: Looks like the challengeView is expanding correctly but not it's subviews. Can you please post or describe how challengeView layout looks like and what constraints does it have.

Comment: Hello, @MikhailVasilev I have added a screenshot of the constraints. The weird thing here is that if I go to another view and come back to this one, then the view's height (of course) the new height (140), and the background now is ok displayed. 140 point height and all the background. I am guessing is something about the way the view is being rendered...

Comment: And what kind of bottom constraint your Stack View has? Is it just bottom to superView?

Comment: @neteot - what are you doing to round the top corners of your `ChallengeView`?

Comment: @DonMag here is the code to do it, don't forget to upvote https://stackoverflow.com/a/46408735/5575955

Comment: @Fabio - there are various methods for rounding view corners. I'm asking the OP because I suspect the method he is using is the cause of his issue.

Comment: @DonMag I am using an extension for `UIView` that uses a `UIBezierPath` and a `CAShapeLayer` to draw the rounded corners on the layer of the view. And then I called that extension on `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and you were totally right. If I removed that the animation work as expected. Do you happen to know what is happening?

Comment: @neteot - layers, such as `CAShapeLayer` do not resize themselves when the view changes size. Take a look at the link in Fabio's comment for one option. That may or may not work for you (depends on various view structure / hierarchy situations), but based on what you've shown it *probably* will.